# Graph Error "code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed", while accessing events/onlineMeetings?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b, microsoft-live-meeting

While trying to access online meeting in order to get the start and end time of the meetings.i am getting below error.

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

**Note : I am able to create the meeting and access it but I want to record the meeting start and end time too.Sometimes the error is ID is malformed althrough I am using the meeting ID returned from the Graph only which is being created.**

Answer (score 0):

Please try `/me/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}`.

Microsoft Graph Explorer users Delegated permission, which mainly takes effect on `/me` endpoint. If you want to use `/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}` , make sure `/users/{userId}` is the current signed-in user.

Please don't query the online meeting of other users. It is only supported by Application permission.

The required Delegated permissions are `OnlineMeetings.Read, OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`.

You can add them like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have already consented those permission for users as well as at application level but nothing works.Still getting same error.

If,in case I try to call the endpoint with application token I am getting still I am getting the same error.
Can you please try this and share me a demo, It would be a great help for me.

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812 Can you tell me how do you call the endpoint with application token? It's not supported to do so in Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Comment: Well It worked somehow with application token yesterday and now again somehow it's not working may be it took token from cache. Actually what I want is to create online meeting which should look like a call and then get that meeting start and end time in order to calculate price on the time spent in that meeting. That is my real agenda.

For now I am creating meeting using /me/onlineMeetings and trying to get the meeting but the real issue is if I was able to get the details still it's not giving me actual start and end time. Please help with this. Thanks

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812 Can you share what you get in the response? I think start and end time should be included in the result.

Comment: Yes it's included but not the actual meeting start and end datetime of the meeting.
It's showing meeting difference of 1 hour but meeting was only for 10 min although I am just passing only the startTime in the parameter of the onlineMeeting.